# Using jQuery next() and ignoring nested lists?

Tags: jquery, list, nested, jquery-selectors, nested-lists

I'm having a little problem here, I want to use next() but I want to ignore nested lists... how can this be done? Right now next will select both the main list and the nested lists.

So say I have...

```
<ul id="mainlist">
<li>1</li>
<li class="selected">2</li>
    <ul id="nested">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>B</li>
    </ul>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

$(".selected").next().css("color", "red");
```

In this situation, the entire "nested" list color changes to red. But I would like the "3" to be red... What can I do in this situation?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

NOTE: This is just an example problem, I'm actually trying to create navigation through list items but figured this code would be easier for an example.

Comment: Simply tried `$(".selected").siblings().next().css("color", "red");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue (causing your code not to work as desired) is that the `ul` tag isn't actually nested in the `li` tag.  The `ul` tag is the next tag after the `li` tag at the same level.  If you mean for it to be nested, then your HTML should look like this:

```
<ul id="mainlist">
<li>1</li>
<li class="selected">2
    <ul id="nested">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>B</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>​
```

And, then your code will work as desired.  You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nfbPp/

If you actually mean for the HTML to be the way it is and you just want to select the next `li` tag that's at the same level as the `.selected` item, then you need different jQuery because `.next()` will select the next sibling which is the `ul` tag.  You would need something like this:

```
$(".selected").nextAll('li:first').css("color", "red");​
```

This will examine all the following siblings and select the ones that match the selector `'li:first'` (which will get just the first `li` tag).

which you can see work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QrUtL/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. The nested list was supposed to be stacked outside of the tags. I wasn't even aware of the existence of nextAll.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your example.

```
$("li.selected").nextAll('li').css("color", "red");
```

For last list element

```
$("li.selected").nextAll('li:last').css("color", "red");
```

Comment: And only for the example. What happens if there are additional `<li>`s after "3"? Your code won't work.

Comment: For last list element $("li.selected").nextAll('li:last').css("color", "red");

Comment: I may be wrong, but the original intent of the question is to get the very next `<li>` element that isn't a nested `<ul>`. In the example he gave, it also happened to be the last element that he was after, but that is irrelevant and specific to the example HTML he posted. Using `.last()` will not help if there is more than one `<li>` following the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".selected").next().not('.selected #nested').css("color", "red");
```

might work, not sure :), try it out

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I'll refrain from downvoting you since you are still new to the site. Where possible, test your answers using something like http://jsFiddle.net before posting them. Oh, and welcome!

Comment: yeah thanks :) well I'm in school right now so I'm not able to test it

Comment: Awesome, finally a productive use of school time! ;-) You realise that jsFiddle is just a website, right? Just open `http://jsfiddle.net` in another tab. Learn to love it.

Answer (score -1):

Using [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and filtering to the first one would work, even though it might not be the most efficient way:

```
$(".selected").nextAll('li').first().css("color", "red");​​​​​
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SsnJy/)